# How to Make a AIX shell script executable?

Tags: shell, aix

I write a simple shell script which could be run like this

$ksh script1

But i donn't know how to execute it.Like

$script1

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works on AIX but on Linux you can say chmod +x script.sh to make it executable using ./script.sh in the script's directory or using /the/full/path/to/script.sh  (if the script isn't in the system path)

Comment: chmod +x script.sh will not look for script.sh in the system's PATH.

Answer (score 1):

to make it executable

```
chmod 755 /folder/of/your/script/script.sh
```

to make it callable from any folder in the system

```
export PATH=$PATH:/folder/of/your/script
```

to make it callable only from script.sh folder

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
$ chmod u+x script1
$ ./script1
```

It's not recommended to add "." to your PATH environment variable due to security reasons.